# Use of Audio Tranformers in Amplification

Tags: amplifier, audio, transformer, signal

I came across this ckt to make a wireless ear phones using **Infrared Signals** from IR LEDs. I am unable to understand the use of **Audio Transformer** here to amplify the audio signal, instead **OpAmps** would sufffice the necessity. There would be a change in input and output impedances in both cases(OpAmps, Transformers), but why would that bother the signal.....[image]

Comment: You could use an op-amp instead of the transformer.  This circuit is unlikely to give good performance though.  I'm guessing you adjust VR1 until the red LED turns on with audio, at which point you have the IR LEDs emitting light which is AM modulated by the signal.  The bias point will be temperature sensitive, there will be non-linear distortion and the receiver will pick up ambient noise.  I did a similar circuit years ago but I used FM modulation and high power low duty cycle drive to the IRLEDs then demodulated with a PLL in the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer does two things:

1. AC coupling (DC blocking)
2. voltage boost/current reduce

This is likely intended to bring the audio signal up in order to saturate the transistor, to get a strong on/off signal from the LEDs.

Comment: As the output of transformer would be an AC signal of zero mean... transistor wont be always in forward active mode (i.e no bias point ) and portion of this voltage(might be negative w.r.t ground) would appear at the base of T1 which equals  V BE(Base to emitter voltage) effecting Ic(collector T1 current).In the negative cycle of the signal(transformer output) transistor goes into cutoff mode as base emitter junction doesn't conduct then.